# Change Background Image in Div using JS

Tags: javascript

I have a div with an id of "imgArea" and I am trying to use JS to change the background image every 3 seconds. Below is the JS. No images are being displayed. What am I missing. Thank you.

```
imgArea = document.getElementById("picArea");

var images = [
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/47/Garmisch-Partenkirchen.JPG/1200px-Garmisch-Partenkirchen.JPG", "https://www.reisenaktuell.com/.imaging/mte/atlas-theme/atlas-gallery/dam/hotels/eigenanreisen/v/hotel-vier-jahreszeiten-garmisch-partenkirchen/bilder/vier-jahreszeiten-garmisch-partenkirchen-grainau-fotolia.jpg/jcr:content/vier-jahreszeiten-garmisch-partenkirchen-grainau-fotolia.jpg", "https://www.alpenferienwohnungen.de/assets/images/a/Garmisch-Partenkirchen-08-6335188a.jpg", "http://www.garmisch-partenkirchen-info.de/header/garmisch-partenkirchen.jpg" ];
var currentImage = 0;

function changeImage() {
    currentImage++;
    if (currentImage > images.length - 1) {
        currentImage = 0;
    }

    imgArea.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[currentImage] + ")";

}
```

The div and code can be seen at this codepen:
https://codepen.io/centem/pen/rdjrLy

Comment: your selector id isn't correct  `imgArea = document.getElementById("imgArea");` & use `setInterval`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gefg6y74/9/)

```js
imgArea = document.getElementById("picArea");

var images = [
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/47/Garmisch-Partenkirchen.JPG/1200px-Garmisch-Partenkirchen.JPG", "https://www.reisenaktuell.com/.imaging/mte/atlas-theme/atlas-gallery/dam/hotels/eigenanreisen/v/hotel-vier-jahreszeiten-garmisch-partenkirchen/bilder/vier-jahreszeiten-garmisch-partenkirchen-grainau-fotolia.jpg/jcr:content/vier-jahreszeiten-garmisch-partenkirchen-grainau-fotolia.jpg", "https://www.alpenferienwohnungen.de/assets/images/a/Garmisch-Partenkirchen-08-6335188a.jpg", "http://www.garmisch-partenkirchen-info.de/header/garmisch-partenkirchen.jpg" ];
var currentImage = 0;

function changeImage() {
 currentImage++;
 if (currentImage > images.length - 1) {
   currentImage = 0;
 }
 imgArea.style.backgroundImage = "url(' "+ images[currentImage] + "')";

}
setInterval(function(){
 changeImage();
}, 3000);
```

```css
#picArea{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="picArea" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="imgArea" style="min-width:50px;min-height:50px;"></div>
```

```js
imgArea = document.getElementById("imgArea");

var images = [
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/47/Garmisch-Partenkirchen.JPG/1200px-Garmisch-Partenkirchen.JPG", "https://www.reisenaktuell.com/.imaging/mte/atlas-theme/atlas-gallery/dam/hotels/eigenanreisen/v/hotel-vier-jahreszeiten-garmisch-partenkirchen/bilder/vier-jahreszeiten-garmisch-partenkirchen-grainau-fotolia.jpg/jcr:content/vier-jahreszeiten-garmisch-partenkirchen-grainau-fotolia.jpg", "https://www.alpenferienwohnungen.de/assets/images/a/Garmisch-Partenkirchen-08-6335188a.jpg", "http://www.garmisch-partenkirchen-info.de/header/garmisch-partenkirchen.jpg" ];
var currentImage = 0;

function changeImage() {
 currentImage++;
 if (currentImage > images.length - 1) {
  currentImage = 0;
 }

 imgArea.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[currentImage] + ")";

}
//call first time
changeImage();
setInterval(changeImage, 3000);
```

```html
<div id="imgArea" style="min-width:500px;min-height:500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the selector is wrong, you selected 'picArea' while your element name is 'imgArea' and then also you are not calling the function, you only declared it.

You should call `changeImage()`

Answer (score 0):

```
imgArea = document.getElementById("picArea");

var images = [
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/47/Garmisch-Partenkirchen.JPG/1200px-Garmisch-Partenkirchen.JPG", "https://www.reisenaktuell.com/.imaging/mte/atlas-theme/atlas-gallery/dam/hotels/eigenanreisen/v/hotel-vier-jahreszeiten-garmisch-partenkirchen/bilder/vier-jahreszeiten-garmisch-partenkirchen-grainau-fotolia.jpg/jcr:content/vier-jahreszeiten-garmisch-partenkirchen-grainau-fotolia.jpg", "https://www.alpenferienwohnungen.de/assets/images/a/Garmisch-Partenkirchen-08-6335188a.jpg", "http://www.garmisch-partenkirchen-info.de/header/garmisch-partenkirchen.jpg" ];
var currentImage = 0;

function changeImage() {
    currentImage++;
    if (currentImage > images.length - 1) {
        currentImage = 0;
    }
    imgArea = document.getElementById("#urid");


}
```